# Отправить "следующее" сообщение из телеграм бота на PHP

Tags: php, telegram, бот

Вопрос прозвучит довольно таки глупым, прошу сильно не ругать. Прежде никак не сталкивался с ботами. Собственно бот для заказа допустим воды. После старта бот спрашивает хотите ли заказать и если последует ответ ДА бот скажет отправьте свой контакт. и если юзер отправит свой контакт то после отправки контакта бот должен отправить уже следующее сообщение с вопросом введите ФИО и после фио уже другой вопрос и т д. Но у меня после отправки контакта заново спрашивает хотите вы заказать и не идет дальше. Помогите пожалуйста. А вот собственно и код.

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
file_put_contents('file.txt', '$data: '.print_r($data, 1)."\n", FILE_APPEND);

$data = $data['callback_query'] ? $data['callback_query'] : $data['message'];   

define('TOKEN', '0000000000:собственно сам токен полученный у bot father');

$message = mb_strtolower(($data['text'] ? $data['text'] : $data['data']),'utf-8');

$method = 'sendMessage';
    $send_data = [
        'text' => 'Хотите ли вы заказать?',
        'reply_markup'  => [
            'resize_keyboard' => true,
            'keyboard' => [
                    [
                        ['text' => 'Да'],
                        ['text' => 'Нет'],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
if ($message=='да') 
{
$method = 'sendMessage';
    $send_data = [
        'text' => 'Пожалуйста нажмите на кнопку отправить контакт',
        'reply_markup'  => [
            'resize_keyboard' => true,
            'keyboard' => [
                    [
                        ['text' => 'Отправить контакт','request_contact'=>true],

                    ]
                    
                    ]
                   

            ]
        ];
        
     $contact=$data['contact']['phone_number'];
    
}
elseif (isset($contact)) {
$method = 'sendMessage';
$send_data = ['text' => 'Напишите ФИО'];
}
elseif ($message=='нет')
{
$method = 'sendMessage';
$send_data = ['text' => 'Спасибо, приходите еще'];
}


$send_data['chat_id'] = $data['chat'] ['id'];

$res = sendTelegram($method, $send_data);

function sendTelegram($method, $data, $headers = [])
{
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/' . $method,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array_merge(array("Content-Type: application/json"))
]);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return (json_decode($result, 1) ? json_decode($result, 1) : $result);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вам надо познакомиться с ООП. Это такой способ думать о программе как о взаимодействии объектов. Это очень естественный для людей способ думать, поэтому он помогает организовать код.

У вас есть *бот* (объект). Бот умеет отправлять *сообщения* (объекты), *пользователь* (тоже объект) на эти сообщения может давать *ответы* (объекты) в зависимости от которых, бот отправит новые сообщения. Получается, что бот -- это набор сообщений и знание о том, какое сообщение текущее; сообщение -- это текст и варианты ответов; вариант ответа -- это текст и ссылка на следующее сообщение.

Если вы ещё не изучили средства [ООП в php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php), то можно обойтись и ассоциативными массивами.

```php
<?php

$bot = [
    'currentMessage' => null,
    'messages' => [
        0 => [
            'text' => 'Хотите ли вы заказать?',
            'answers' => [
                [
                    'text' => 'Да',
                    'next' => 1,
                ],
                [
                    'text' => 'Нет',
                    'next' => 3,
                ],
                 
            ],
        ],
        1 => [
            'text' => 'Пожалуйста нажмите на кнопку отправить контакт',
            'answers' => [
                [
                    'text' => 'Отправить контакт',
                    'next' => 2
                ],
            ],
        ],
        2 => [
            'text' => 'Напишите ФИО',
            'answers' => [],
        ],
        3 => [
            'text' => 'Спасибо, приходите еще',
            'answers' => [],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Пока тут нет кода логики. Но думаю, что глядя на эту структуру, вы уже можете понять, как эта логика будет устроена. Вся фишка в том, что объекты одного типа имеют одинаковую структуру и могут быть обработаны одинаково.

Проговорим логику словами:

**1. Узнать какое сообщение текущее**

В своём примере вы делаете это косвенно. Если ответ "нет", то подразумевается, что текущий вопрос "Хотите ли вы заказать?". Можно оставить и так, но лучше передавать текущее сообщение в явном виде (API телеграм бота наверняка поддерживает какой-нибудь идентификатор сообщения).

**2. Найти ответ пользователя в текущем сообщении**

Можно просто сопоставить текст ответа или использовать идентификаторы.

**3. Перейти к следующему сообщению**

Следующее сообщение указано в next ответа. Если сообщение не предусматривает ответов, то диалог заканчивается.

```php
function messages_getMessage(array $messages, int $messageId): ?array {
    return $messages[$messageId]?? null;
}

function answers_getAnswer(array $answers, string $answerId): ?array {
    $result = null;
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        if ($answer['text'] === $answerId) {
            $result = $answer;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

function bot_init(array &$bot, int $messageId) {
    $message = messages_getMessage($bot['messages'], $messageId);
    if ($message) {
        $bot['currentMessage'] = $message;
    } else {
        // тут можно как-то обработать ошибку, я просто начну с начала
        $bot['currentMessage'] = $bot['messages'][0];
    }
}

function bot_reply(array &$bot, string $answerId): array {
    $answer = answers_getAnswer($bot['currentMessage']['answers'], $answerId);
    if ($answer) {
        $bot['currentMessage'] = $bot['messages'][$answer['next']];
    }

    return $bot['currentMessage'];
}

// например
bot_init($bot, 0);
$message = bot_reply($bot, ''); // начинаем диалог
echo $message['text'] . "\n";
$answer = readline( implode("/", array_column($message['answers'], 'text')) . ":\n");
$message2 = bot_reply($bot, $answer);
echo $message2['text'] . "\n";
```

---

Остаётся только завязать это с телеграмом. Думаю, вы справитесь. Думайте о программе как о взаимодействии объектов и тогда код перестанет быть загадкой. В первую очередь важно *кто* и *что делает*, как делает -- это второй вопрос.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за внятный ответ.